# CakePHP HTML helper CSS tag and Apache Alias

Tags: cakephp, apache2, cakephp-1.3

As a relative newcomer to CakePHP, I'm hoping for some advice on the "right" way of configuring Apache and CakePHP to find included files (CSS, JavaScript, etc).

If my server's `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www` and I install and configure CakePHP in `/var/www/somepath/cakeapp` I can access the application as expected at the URL http://example.com/somepath/cakeapp.

However, if I use the HTML helper to generate the CSS link tag in my default layout, I start to run into trouble.  For example, the code

```
echo $html->css('styles');
```

produces this tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/somepath/cakeapp/css/styles.css" />
```

However, the CSS actually lives in `/somepath/cakeapp/app/webroot/css`.

If the CakePHP app were the only thing on my domain, I could point the `DocumentRoot` at `/var/www/somepath/cakeapp/app/webroot` as the documentation suggests and all would (presumably) be well.  However, that's not an option for me.

Is there a generally accepted correct way of configuring Apache and CakePHP so that the HTML helper can produce the correct link tag?

**Edit:** I feel there must be some combination of CakePHP configuration and Apache Aliases that I haven't run across yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/somepath/cakeapp/css/styles.css` is actually the correct path that needs to be displayed in the links.

The reason why it gets displayed as such is because of the **.htaccess** file in your cakeapp directory that redirects (rewrites) requests to the cakeapp/app/webroot directory.

Now, the reason why this structure even exists is because generally, you have "public" and "non-public" parts in your application. The "non-public" parts contain the PHP code including controllers, models, views, plugins, cake library, etc. The "public" parts include the css, scripts, and image files.

Now, you *could* make your /var/www/html folder as your app directory to make it secure. In order to completely configure your application to your liking, check the cakeapp/app/bootstrap.php file and change the relevant settings. You can learn more about that [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1568/Configuration-and-application-bootstrapping).

In short, no worries. The path you see is right!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  In the end, as you say, my configuration was fine.  What tripped me up was that I was accidentally referring to a style sheet that didn't exist.  Apparently, when it didn't find the file, CakePHP went on to interpret the request as it normally would, looking for a `CssController` (and, of course, not finding it.)

Comment: Ah, I generally keep my Net console in Firebug to check for non-loading resources like css, js, images, and ajax requests. Anyway, glad you could work it out @eaj

Answer (score 1):

Try defining RewriteBase in your .htaccess files in Cake's root directory, /app and /app/webroot to point to your subdirectory. Set them to the respective paths, /somepath/, /somepath/app/ and /somepath/app/webroot/